# What's causing mottled leaves on my Schefflera?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, leaves

What is causing this discoloration on my Schefflera's leaves?

[image][image][image]

It's like a water color effect. There may be embedded bugs in some leaves.

Comment: I see tiny black  specks on the  leaves in various places which appear to be insects of some sort - might be spider mite, any sign of bits of webbing anywhere? Check the whole plant please, especially in the junctions of leaf stems. Otherwise, magnifying glass to inspect what they are... a long term infestation of spider mite could cause this mottled effect...

Answer (score 3):

This plant is deficient in a number of chemicals. Some people say 'nutrients' but the chemistry plants need, fertilizer is not at all food.  Plants need these chemicals to make their own food for energy, to grow, to root and to make flowers and fruit.

This is a deficiency in Magnesium, possibly.  Fertilizing gets far more complex, a lot of symptoms depict a number of different elements missing and or being hampered by pH of the soil.

We need to know what you have added.  What was in the soil you used when you planted this Scheffelera?  Is this in potting soil?  Do you have a pH meter of any kind?  Are these leaves on the bottom of the plant or are they on the top of the plant?  Newer leaves or older leaves?  What are you watering methods?  Growing plants is very much a chemistry experiment, especially when plants depend on the human's input completely for growth in a pot.

[magnesium deficiency of Scheffelera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_deficiency_(plants))

[image: magnesium deficiency cucumber]

Comment: It must've been a little displaced soil. I have 4 scheffeleras and have had some for years. I've been having tropicals, houseplants and succulents for 35+ years and I've never had ph problems or deficiencies. I looked in to the magnesium deficiency and it seems like that might be the problem but I'm having a hard time beleiving that. There are a couple of random leaves on this same mottled leaf scheffelera that have tiny brown spots that are slightly raised as if it's is embedded. I'm completely miffed with the mottled leaves but I'm going to look deeper into magnesium a deficiency. Thank you